# How to fix the CORS error between Angular and Nest.js?

Tags: angular, cors, nestjs

I have application where I have a Nest.js server and Angular front-end. Generally speaking, I am trying to send the request from the client to the server with `withCredentials` flag set on `true` because I am getting `HttpOnly` cookies from the server that I would like to set in the client's browser. Here is the code sippet on the client side:

```
const request$ = this.http.post<any>(requestUrl, requestBody, {
  withCredentials: true
});
```

So, when I am sending the request to the server, here is what I am getting as an error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:4201/api/proxy/auth/login' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
> wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The
> credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
> controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I was trying to play around with the server and its CORS settings, but it didn't seem to help. So, at this moment I have only this there:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
```

So, how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here is how I was able to resolve this issue. I have deleted this `{ cors: true }` from the application constructor and instead used built-in CORS method by the instance of the application:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

app.enableCors({
  origin: ['http://localhost:4200'],
  credentials: true
});
```

Comment: You'll need to add the production url to prevent cors when you deploy to production

Answer (score 0):

Dokichan, here is a comprehensive solution for **NestJs CORS with localhost whitelisting and methods** => if you want to stick it in as options-parameters on the create method, you can do this:

```
const whitelist = [
      'http://localhost:3000',
      'http://localhost:3001',
      'http://localhost:3002',
      'http://localhost:8000',
      'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
      'http://127.0.0.1:3001',
      'http://127.0.0.1:3002',
      'http://10.0.2.2:3000',
    ];

const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    logger,
    cors: {
      methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
      origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (!origin) {
          callback(null, true);
          return;
        }
        if (
          whitelist.includes(origin) || // Checks your whitelist
          !!origin.match(/yourdomain\.com$/) // Overall check for your domain
        ) {
          console.log('allowed cors for:', origin);
          callback(null, true);
        } else {
          console.log('blocked cors for:', origin);
          callback(new ImATeapotException('Not allowed by CORS'), false);
        }
      },
    },
  });
```

Good luck!